# Finding the custom GATT services and characteristics of Movesense sensors

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, movesense

I’m using the custom gatt package found in `movesense-device-lib/samples/bin/release/Movesense-custom_gattsvc_app_w_bootloader.zip` for my project. I can't create my own package since there's a bug in the mac compiler.

I really need to the service and characteristic `UUIDs` for `ECG` (in fact if I could get the `services/characteristics` of the other features in the package that’d be great too)

There're links to a sites that give the uuid for certain characteristics and services, such as these ones:

[GATT Services](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services/)

[GATT Characteristics](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/characteristics/)

Unfortunately, since the movesense package is custom made, it uses different UUIDs. I tried backtracing them by writing a function on my client that pulls an arraylist of the services and the characteristics, but no luck :(

Comment: Install the *nRF Connect* app (by Nordic Semiconductor) from the App Store. It will allow to inspect any BLE device incl. services and characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

The *custom_gattsvc_app* is a sample app that shows how to use Movesense CustomGATTService to implement your own (or someone elses) GATT service. The sample shows how to do that by implementing the (partial) "Medical Thermometer" GATT service, nothing else.

To access all of the Movesense API over BLE you'll need to use the *movesense-mobile-lib* or implement your own protocol over your own GATT service. I'm not aware of any 3rd party ECG GATT service specifications.

The movesense-device-lib release 2.0 will include a sample that provides access to most of the Movesense API services and easy expansion over a simple GATT protocol.

*Full Disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*

Comment: Hi Petri where can I find this info ? I am also looking for the custom uuids for the gatt